# Why does the WorkItemLinkCollection.Add method return numbers?

Tags: powershell, tfs, client

I'm trying to add a link to a WorkItemLinkCollection with it's Add() method. It seems to work, however I am puzzled why it returns even numbers and prints it on my Powershell console. What is the point and need for it? What does the code in Add() actually look like?

```
$newLink = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemLink($AClinkTypeEnd, $requirementItem.Id, $AC.Id)
$requirementItem.WorkItemLinks.Add($newLink)
```

Comment: The `Add` method returns a System.Int32, which is the index in this collection of the newly added WorkItemLink. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff737508%28v%3dvs.120%29). If you do not want that, just prepend `[void]` or append `| Out-Null` to the command.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I would vey much want to see the implementation of the method however. I found IList.Add(Object) Method implementation from .NET Framework 4.8 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_IList_Add_System_Object_). Are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest to the answer I was looking for was Theo's comment under my question:
"The Add method returns a System.Int32, which is the index in this collection of the newly added WorkItemLink. See the docs. If you do not want that, just prepend [void] or append | Out-Null to the command."

Also I recommend checking out IList.Add(Object) Method implementation from .NET Framework 4.8 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

*What is the point and need for it?*

This is the expected behavior. Just as the comment  indicated:

The returned numbers simply mean how many work item links you have added for this collection.

*What does the code in Add() actually look like?*

```
public int Add(
    WorkItemLink link
)
```

**link**

Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemLink

The [WorkItemLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff732476%28v%3Dvs.120%29) to add to this collection.